# Regression line with geom_bar() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, trendline

I am trying to add regression lines to my bar plot. So far, I added a linear regression to green bars, and I can also add a trend line using the purple bars' data. What I have not been able to do is to apply this linear model to the sum of green and purple bars. The closest I have gotten is to add a simple line of the sum of the bars using `stat_summary()`. Replicable code is below. Thank you!

```
decadeCount <- data.frame(Year=seq(1850, 2010, 10), 
          TS=floor(runif(17, min=0, max=17)), H=floor(runif(17, min=0, max=23)))


decadeCount.m <- melt(decadeCount, id = "Year")
names(decadeCount.m)[2]<-"type"
names(decadeCount.m)[3]<-"count"
decadeCount.m[[1]] <- as.character(decadeCount.m[[1]])
decadeCount.m[[1]] <- paste0(decadeCount.m[[1]], "'s")


ggplot(decadeCount.m[order(decadeCount.m$type,decreasing=T),]) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = Year, y = count, fill = factor(type, levels=c("H","TS"))),
           stat = "identity",  position = "stack", show.legend = F) +
  geom_smooth(data=decadeCount.m[decadeCount.m$type == "TS",],aes(x = Year, y = count, group=1),
              method = "lm", se= FALSE, color = "firebrick1", size = 2) +
  stat_summary(aes(Year, count),fun.y = sum, geom = "smooth", show.legend = F, group=1) +
  labs(x = "Decade") +
  scale_y_continuous("Count", breaks = seq(5,35,5), limits=c(0,35),
                     expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0.001, 0.05)),
                     sec.axis = dup_axis(name = NULL, labels = NULL)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0.05, 0.05))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#944F9F","#6BBD45"))
```

[image: Bar plot]

Comment: Try use `dplyr` to create an additional column which contains the sum of green and purple bar and plot the regression line using the new column. Also try use `geom_col()` where you can specify x and y as identity values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly summarise the data within the `ggplot` command and produced the desired plot. I've also used `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar`, because you're using the exact values from the columns.

```
ggplot(decadeCount.m[order(decadeCount.m$type,decreasing=T),]) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = Year, y = count, fill = factor(type, levels=c("H","TS"))),
           show.legend = F) +
  geom_smooth(data=decadeCount.m %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarise(count=sum(count)),
              aes(x = Year, y = count, group=1),
              method = "lm", se= FALSE, color = "firebrick1", size = 2) +
  labs(x = "Decade") +
  scale_y_continuous("Count", breaks = seq(5,35,5), limits=c(0,35),
                     expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0.001, 0.05)),
                     sec.axis = dup_axis(name = NULL, labels = NULL)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0.05, 0.05))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#944F9F","#6BBD45"))
```

[image]